# AngularJS: Setting properties while keeping a binding: is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have some property in a service that I want to set equal to the data I get back from a network call, I can do something like this:

```
//SERVICE//
thisService.property = data;
//SERVICE//
```

and in my controller I can do:

```
//CONTROLLER//
this.property = ThisService.property;
//CONTROLLER//
```

so that I can bind to it in the HTML and have it dynamically update:

```
//VIEW//
{{property}}
//VIEW//
```

However, as you may know, this does not work. The controller.property remains undefined, as this line:

```
thisService.property = data;
```

will create a new reference for thisService.property, and the old one, set in the controller, will not point to the new data.

So, what I have to do is wrap the data in another object, and do something like this:

```
//SERVICE//
thisService.property = {};
thisService.property.property = data;
//SERVICE//

//CONTROLLER//
this.property = ThisService.property;
//CONTROLLER

//VIEW//
{{property.property}}
//VIEW//
```

This is rather crude and ugly. Is there a better, cleaner way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a getter.

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'property',
                      { get: function() { return ThisService.property; }});
```

Now the controller's `property` will always refer to the current service's `property`.

If the service's value is set only once and never changes again, then I'd recommend using a promise though. That would tell more about what's going on.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iMH5Cx0IcPOcXgFesERQ)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to expose service object to the view sos you don't have to make "crazy" stuff to your service:

```
this.service = ThisService;
```

and in view use

```
{{service.property}}
```

Comment: Yes but is this really better? This adds all the properties of the service to be watched and accessed, but I only want to access some of them. Is there any performance hit with doing this?

Comment: I would say that it's not that bad actually. Nothing gets copied it's just a reference. In addition there are no additional watchers set up for service properties in this case. Performance hit is minimal.